# BB headless app issue

Tags: qt, blackberry, headless

in blackberry native development, can headless app share or use the sandbox of UI app if yes then how? if No then what is the way to use the data of ui app?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/index.html) you must write a two executables. One provides the headless functionality, the other the UI. The two executables are able to communicate with each other and together make up a headless application.

Comment: Thanks Richard,actually i am using some database in my UI part and i want to access that database by headless part so that my headless app can make some decision according to the database.. can i access that database in headless part... actually this is my first time i encountered with headless application...

Comment: Yes of course. Only one process will be able to have the database open in write mode at a time though.